# UI-Router issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement ui-router(i.e `$stateProvider`) with my AngularApp.

My Logic is I have different modules. suppose  Album (it have various views.)

What I am trying to implement is creating it as module. That means single controller for all states as well mixed logic in single controller file.

1. I created 1 files names list.

my state would be like this

```
.state('album', {url: '/album', templateUrl: 'views/album/list.html'}) 
//code would like this.
<li class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p class="list-item">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    <a class="cursor" href="#/poet/detail/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a> 
    </p>
</li>
```

Now when we click it move to detail page. Having various tabs to render on same page. Corresponding states would be like this

```
.state('album.detail', {url: '/detail/:itemId', templateUrl: 'views/album/album.detail.html'}) 
.state('album.comment', {url: '/comment/:itemId', templateUrl: 'views/album/album.comment.html'})   
.state('album.tracklist', {url: '/tracklist/:itemId', templateUrl: 'views/album/album.tracklist.html'})   
.state('album.review', {url: '/review/:itemId', templateUrl: 'views/album/album.review.html'}) 

//All states have same controller, I would call services on switch condition on (states). Now issue is when I click on detail link from the list page I mentioned earlier it navigates to the base url.
//Instead of linking this http://0.0.0.0:3000/#/poets -> ttp://0.0.0.0:3000/#/poets/detail/12 It transfer to the base url i.e. - http://0.0.0.0:3000/#
```

Comment: use ng-href="#/poet/detail/{{item.id}}"

Comment: I did before but results same.

Comment: @Amita. I have requested same on skype. Can you pls help.

Comment: try this `ui-sref="album.detail({ itemId: item.id })`.

Comment: I have got the issue I haven't included the **ui-view=""** but I am still not clear why would I include this. I want to navigate from list to detail page. Thr would different states as I mentioned. Isn't it. Please Explain..

Comment: check the [ui-view directive documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view)

Comment: As you have stated album.detail, it means it as child of album. So the parent should have the view. Let's say for example left side is menu and right hand is view. If you want to keep it as seperate state remove that .dot